# Denied access to blender add-on

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am learning how to create an add-on for Blender, by watching this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uahfuypQQ04 
But when I try to run it with blender I have this message:

> "Access denied: 'c:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\Lib\site-packages\pip' Consider using
>   the --user option or check the permissions."

The code:

```
#_init_.py

    bl_info = {
    "name" : "Bruh",
    "author" : "JP",
    "description" : "Simple Test Addon",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "location" : "",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

def register():
...

def unregister():
...

import bpy

from . test_op    import Test_OT_Operator
from . test_panel import Test_PT_Panel

classes = (Test_OT_Operator, Test_PT_Panel)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

=

```
 #test_op.py

import bpy

class Test_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.cursor_center"
    bl_label = "Simple operator"
    bl_description = "Center 3d cursor"

    def execute(self, context);
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

=

```
#test_panel.py

impot bpy

class Test_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "Test_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_category = "Test Addon"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('view3d.cursor_center', text = "Center 3D cursor")
```

Does anyone know a way to give this access or solve this problem in any way?

Comment: You don't have the required permissions to install a package using pip. When does this error happen?

Comment: Hi. What do you run that gives this error? Please include any relevant code that you are using that creates this error. Also, please edit the title to be *specific* to the problem you are having.

Comment: @rjg - It happens when I try to run the addon for blender, I press ctrl + shift + p and select Blender Start, then I select where is blender and It opens, but VSC shows error after a few seconds

Comment: @RayMairlot First really thank you for helping me with my grammar and formatting. I edited my text so that it is correct and put my codes into it. Also I tried to be more specific with my title, I hope it is more clear.